# Uploading CSV with accented/special Characters using VFpage

Tags: visualforce, error, csv, upload, character-encoding

I'm currently working on a vfpage that can upload records using CSVs similar to [**`this`**](http://www.sfdcpoint.com/salesforce/import-csv-file-using-apex-visualforce/) project. But, the records in the CSV may contain accented characters from spanish alphabet. So, when I attempt to upload a csv with accented characters, those characters will instead look like a question mark (?) or unrecognizable.

Yes I have tried base64encoding and I'm avoiding the process of going through notepads or notepad++ to correct the characters before upload.

I really appreciate the help guys if you have any idea about this.

Comment: Please check if the files are UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: Can you give use a small sample CSV with some of the problem characters?

Comment: Hello, guys. I have decided to require the users to use specificied excel file extension: CSV UTF-8. After a period of relentless searching, it seems that there really is currently no existing workaround in the internet for this. Thanks anyway, guys.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the encoding of the file to UTF-8

This is the sf documentation on how to do it https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000324657&type=1&mode=1